# checks if a tree is a full binary tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

I have to write an algorithm that checks if a tree is full binary tree (each node, except the leaves, must have 2 children), but I don't know if this version is correct.

```
 isComplete(u) 
{
        if(u == NULL)
                return false
        else
        {
                left = isComplete(u.left);
                right = isComplete(u.right);
                complete = left && right;

                return complete.
        }
}
```

Comment: A first thing you could do is to try it on some small examples. I think you'll have a good idea of whether this works rather quickly. If it seems to work, then the next step is to formally prove the algorithm correctness.

Comment: Have you done a test run or two, perhaps?

Comment: @Steven Dang! You beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: I tested the algorithm "by hand", since we have not yet seen how to implement trees in a programming language. In the cases I have tried, the algorithm seems to work, but I would not want something to have escaped me, since the proposed solution seems totally different.

Comment: Have you tried it on the complete binary tree of height $0$, i.e., a single node? Does it work? Have you tried it on the complete binary tree of height $1$?

Comment: I've tried both and it seems to return true. Anyway, I realized that I have used the wrong terminology: the tree must be a full binary tree and not a complete binary tree.

Comment: Okay, let me ask you this question then. Run you algorithm on the complete binary tree of height $0$ consisting of the sole node $v$. There exactly $3$ calls of your function. The fist call is `isComplete(v)` and it returns true if and only if both `isComplete(v.left)` and  `isComplete(v.right)` return true. What is the return value of `isComplete(v.left)`? What is the return value of `isComplete(v.right)`?

Comment: Thanks, I found the error: for some reason I was continuing to do $false \wedge false \equiv true$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your algorithm is recursive you need to consider:

- the initial / final case : the leaves
- and the general case : the nodes

For example in the case of factorial:

- the initial case $f(1) = 1$
- and the general case is $f(n) = n*f(n-1)$

Formally, to prove its correctness you can use induction.